Cannot get rid of this printer
My office has two identical printers, one of which I use. The other is in the president's office. Various programs appear to select the WRONG printer despite the fact I set the correct printer as the default. Printing to the president's printer is not helping my job status. But I cannot for the life of me GET RID OF THAT PRINTER. If I remove it, it just comes right back.
I have tried editing the cups-browsed.conf and turning off all of the auto discover options there. Nothing seems to work. Oddly, lpstat -p does not show the "ghost printer" at all.

This question is similar to: How do I disable automatic remote printer installation?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

There are 9 answers to this question. Make sure you try them all.

It might not be similar to the old question suggested above. More information is needed.  Ubuntu does run with multiple IDs.  Does @Scott Franco have sudo access to the Ubuntu system?  If printing on the president's printer isn't politic, that company president is going to take an even dimmer view of someone tweeking the default printer away from his/her office if indeed they both share the same multi-user Ubuntu system in that office (as different users of course)

A simple DuckDuckGo search found https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2015/01/lpadmin-examples/ . You can set your system's default printer with sudo lpoptions -d YourPrinterName. Then, restart all your applications, or simply reboot with sudo shutdown -r now.

@waltinator - your suggested  commands require sudo, we don't yet know if this person has admin access to the system.

Then run lpoptions without sudo:  e.g. lpoptions -d YourPrinterName, and it will set the default printer for your userid, not for the whole system. The printer deletion suggestion (paragraph #11) has a system-wide effect,  it requires sudo.

sudo lpadmin -x printerName

Thanks, haven't seen that page, will try it and post results.
